# Java String Split issue for latitude and longitude

Tags: java, split

I'm writing a constructor for class `LatLong` that should take a string representation such as `"3430E 5256N"` ,and convert that to two double numbers, latitude and longitude.

How should I do that?

I wrote this so far but don't know how to remove the E and N when splitting:

```
public LatLong(String latlong) { 
    String[] parts = latlong.split(" ");
    String latitude = parts[0];
    String longitude = parts[1];
}
```

Also, if a user entered 34.5, it it will take 34 and multiply `0.5*60` to get the minutes which is `30`, which would look like `3430`, and depending on the number, it should determine what cardinality it is - North, South, East, or West.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

```
String latitude = parts[0].substring(0,4);
String longitude = parts[1].substring(0,4);
```

Comment: but (0,4) will give me 3430E right? so if i want 3430 only it will be (0,3) ?

Comment: @MaramAl-Zu'bi No, [Here](https://ideone.com/sBM7h4) is the working demo. If you read the docs, it says that `...extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.` which is `(0,4)` in your example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply retrieve the double values from the input string using `Scanner`.

```
Double lat, long;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(latlong);
scanner.useDelimiter("[^\\d,]");

while (scanner.hasNextDouble() || scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        if (lat == null) {
            lat = scanner.nextDouble(); // First setting the latitude
        } else {
            long = scanner.nextDouble(); // Then longitude and stopping
            break;
        }
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}

scanner.close(); // Edit: forgot the close in original answer
```

Any other conversions (as you mentioned 34.5 as input) can be done easily afterwards once you have the doubles themselves.

Note that the *E* and *N* letters are part of the latitude and longitude definitions. Regardless your question, I believe that you should eventually save them also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to remove any last letter of a string, use:

```
String latitude = parts[0].substring(0,parts[0].length()-1); 
String longitude = parts[1].substring(0,parts[1].length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String coordinates = "3430E 5256N";

    String[] split = coordinates.split(" ");
    String latitude = split[0];
    String longitude = split[1];

    int indexOfPoint = latitude.indexOf(".");
    if (indexOfPoint != -1) {
        //we don't have point in string representations, so just remove the letter
        latitude = latitude.replace("E", "");
        latitude = latitude.replace("W", "");
    } else {
        //the string representation contains a point
        String valueAfterPoint = latitude.substring(indexOfPoint);
        valueAfterPoint = valueAfterPoint.replace("E", "");
        valueAfterPoint = valueAfterPoint.replace("W", "");
        double minutes = Double.parseDouble(valueAfterPoint);
        minutes*=60;
        latitude+=minutes;
    }

    //the samething with longitude, just remove letters N and S in replace statements.
```

Comment: what I wanted to create a set latitude method?
 which is a method to set latitude in digrees and minutes